# How to resize chartjs in bootstrap columns for different browsers

Tags: css, browser, chart.js, resize

I have chartjs charts running in bootstrap row and cols.
The number of columns per row can be changed dynamically.

e.g. I'd rebuild my rows with either of these markups

```
const twoColum = spacerColumn +
                "<div class='colm col-md-5' id='col0' ></div>" +
                "<div class='colm col-md-5' id='col1' ></div>" +
                spacerColumn;

const threeColum = spacerColumn +
                "<div class='colm col-md-3' id='col0' onClick='DrillDownClick(this.id)'></div>" +
                "<div class='colm col-md-3' id='col1' onClick='DrillDownClick(this.id)'></div>" +
                "<div class='colm col-md-3' id='col2' onClick='DrillDownClick(this.id)'></div>" +
                spacerColumn + spacerColumn;
```

for IE 11 the following works

```
.columnCanvas
{
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

and the chart properties

```
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
```

But this does not work in Edge or Chrome.

By changing the properties to

```
    responsive: false,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,   (or false,..no difference)
```

it works in Edge, Chrome etc. (with some overlapping of the bootstrap columns and rows, which I could fix with css, but then it is no longer responsive to screen resizing and in IE 11, my charts are extremely small.

[image]

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by determinig which browser is in use.
so,

```
var isIEBrowser = true;

if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) || (!!document.documentMode == true))
{
    isIEBrowser = true;
}
else
{
    isIEBrowser = false;
}
```

and where I build my charts

```
options:
{
    responsive: isIEBrowser,
    maintainAspectRatio: isIEBrowser,
```

and ensured the bootstrap columns which are the parent of the Canvas are set with

```
style='position: relative; height:99%; width:99%;'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by determinig which browser is in use.

```
if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) || (!!document.documentMode == true))
    {
        isIEBrowser = true;
    }
    else
    {
        isIEBrowser = false;
    }
```

so where I build my charts

```
options:
{
    responsive: isIEBrowser,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
```